# Unable to create query using JPAQuery cross joins

Tags: querydsl

jpaQuery.from(tableA,tableb). (how to write the below condition) in query dsl
tableA.id = tableb.id(+)

how to write left outer join using query dsl??

here is the sample code written to write eq join

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

QTableA tableA = QTableA.tableA; QTableB tableB = QTableB.tableB

query.from(tableA ,tableB).where(tableA.id.eq(tableB.id)). singleResult(tableB.name);

The above query i have written eq join. How to write LEFT OUTER JOIN ??

Can you please help me Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a entity relation between the two entities to write a left outer join using Querydsl JPA.

e.g.

```
from(tableA).leftJoin(tableA.ref, tableB)...
```